# Maximize the function $f(x, y) = 2xy + 3x$ under the constraint $x + 2y = 83$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & f(x, y) := 2xy + 3x\\ \text{subject to} & x + 2y = 83\end{array}$$

I can apply, for example, the Lagrange theorem since its assumptions are satisfied and computing the Lagrange system I get the critical point is $x=43$, $y=20$. However, the Lagrange theorem gives only the necessary condition. How can I show that the function has a min/max at $x=43, y=20$?It looks like I cannot use Weirstrass theorem since the set $x + 2y = 83$ is closed but not bounded..

Comment: It's easy enough to observe that if you substitute the constraint into the objective function, you get a parabola that opens upward.

Comment: Study the one variable function $x(83-x)+3x$

Comment: Without using *what*?

Comment: Just substitute $83-2y$ for $x$ or $\frac {83-x}2$ for $y$ and set the derivative to $0$ and solve.  Let $g(x) = f(x,\frac {83-x}2) = 2x\frac{83-x}2 + 3x = x(83-x)+3x$ as dmtri suggested.  And $g'(x) = -2x + 86$ and $g'(x)=  0$ means $x=43$ and $y=20$.  You can verify that is a maximum by pluggin in values or noting $g''(x) = -2 < 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @dmtri's comment, solving the constraint for $y$ yields $y= \frac12(83-x)$. Substituting this into the objective function yields $$f(x) = 2x\cdot\frac12(83-x) +3x = x(83-x) + 3x = x(86-x) = -x^2 + 86x.$$
Now, the graph $\{(x,f(x)): x\in\mathbb R\}$ is a descending parabola. We can write the quadratic $-x^2+86x$ in vertex form: $-x^2+86x = a(x-h)^2+k$ where the coordinates of the vertex are $(h,k)$. Expanding the vertex form, we have $ax^2 - 2ahx + ah^2+k$. Since $f(0)=0$, we immediately see that $ah^2+k=0$. Moreover, $a$ must match the coefficient of $x^2$, so $a=-1$. This yields $-x^2 +2hx = -x^2+86x$, and hence $h=43$. It follows then that $k= -ah^2 = 43^2 = 1849$. Since $f$ is concave, the maximum value that $f$ obtains is thus $1849$.

To solve this using calculus, we first note that $f$ is continuously differentiable and that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=-\infty$, so the maximum must occur at a point where $f'(x)=0$. Differentiating, we have $f'(x) = -2x +86$. Solving $f'(x)=0$ yields $x=43$. Now, $f'(x)>0$ for $x<43$ so $f$ is increasing on $(-\infty,43)$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x>43$ so $f$ is decreasing on $(43,\infty)$, so $x=43$ is a local (and because $f$ is concave, global) maximum for $f$. We evaluate $f(43) = 43(86-43) = 43^2 = 1849$.

Although the above method is simpler, we can still use Lagrange multipliers to solve this problem. To solve
\begin{align}
\max&\quad f(x,y)\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad g(x,y)=0
\end{align}
we form the system of equations
\begin{align}
\nabla f(x,y) &= \lambda\nabla g(x,y)\\
g(x,y) &= 0,
\end{align}
where $\nabla$ denotes the gradient operator. We compute
$$
\nabla f(x,y) = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) = (2y+3, 2x)
$$
and
$$
\lambda\nabla g(x,y) = \lambda \left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \right) = (\lambda, 2\lambda),
$$
which yields the system of equations:
\begin{align}
2y + 3 &= \lambda\\
2x &= 2\lambda\\
x + y - 83 &= 0.
\end{align}
By inspection, $x=\lambda$, whence $y = \frac12(x-3)$. Substituting into the third equation, we find that $$x = x + \frac12(x-3) - 83 = 0 \implies x=43.$$
Therefore $y = \frac12(43-3) = 20$, and the maximum of $f$ is obtained at $(43,20)$, with $f(43,20) = 1849$. To prove that $(43,20)$ is indeed a maximum, we consider the Lagrangian function $L(x,y) = f(x,y)-\lambda g(x,y) = 2xy+3x - \lambda(x+2y-83)$ and the bordered Hessian matrix
$$
\mathcal HL(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial x^2}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial x\partial y}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial x\partial \lambda}\\
\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial y\partial x}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial y^2}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial y\partial\lambda}\\\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial \lambda\partial x}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial\lambda \partial y}&\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial\lambda^2}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&2&-1\\2&0&-2\\-1&-2&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $\det(\mathcal HL(43, 20))=-8<0$, we conclude that $(43,20)$ is indeed a maximum.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation, but suppose that I wanted to use the Lagrange system to compute the critical points. How could I show that the critical point found is a actually a max? May I use the fact that the function $$\begin{array}{ll} f(x, y) := 2xy + 3x\\ \text{subject to} & x + 2y = 83\end{array}$$
  is negative coercive in that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=-\infty$ so that exists a max? Or could I use the quasiconcavity of the objective function?

Comment: @LearningProb I have added the Lagrange multiplier method to my answer.

Comment: Thabk you, but Lagrange only gives the necessary condition in such a case. Doesn't it?How could I prove that the critical point is actually a global maximum?

Comment: Once I get the critical point in the lagrange system how do I proceed? Perhaps the point is simply a saddle or a minimum rather then a maximum

Comment: @LearningProb In this case the bordered Hessian matrix is constant with negative determinant, so any solution to the Lagrangian equations is a maximum. I've edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but do you think there is another way beyond bordered hessian to say that the function has a maximum ? Thank you.